# Can't use await in IDBRequest handler transaction finishes before all required async handlers

Tags: jquery, async-await, indexeddb

These are requests that use `IndexedDB` and `awaites`:

```
openRequest.onsuccess = async () => {
    db = openRequest.result
    const {transaction, objectStore, cursorRequest} = getIndexedDbTriplet()

    cursorRequest.onsuccess = e => {
        // @ts-ignore
        const cursor = e.target.result

        // @ts-ignore
        objectStore.count().onsuccess = async e => {
            // @ts-ignore
            if (e.target.result === 0) {
                console.log(`Db doesn't have cart products, trying to fetch from server`)
                if (await isAuthenticated()) {
                    await $.get('/Areas/Cart/GetProducts', products, () => {
                        if (products.length === 0) {
                            console.log(`Server also doesn't have cart products`)
                            return
                        } else {
                            $.each(products, (_, product) => {
                                objectStore.add(product)
                            })
                            console.log(`Added products to db`)
                        }
                    })
                }
            } else if (await isAuthenticated()) {
                await $.get('Areas/Cart/GetProducts', products, () => {
                    if (products.length == 0) {
                        console.log(`Server doesn't have products, uploading to it from db`)
                        if (cursor) {
                            $.post('Areas/Cart/AddProduct', cursor.value)
                        }
                        cursor.continue()
                    }
                    console.log(`Uploaded products to server`)
                })
            }
            transaction.oncomplete = e => console.log(`why`)

            objectStore.getAll().onsuccess = e => {
                // @ts-ignore
                products = e.target.result
                let productsLength = products.length

                let decrementCount = 0
                if (products.length % 4 !== 0) {
                    while (productsLength % 4 !== 0) {
                        productsLength--
                        decrementCount++
                    }
                }

                const div = $('<div>')

                for (let i = 0; i < productsLength; i += 4) {
                    const row = getRow()
                    appendCartProductWidget(products[i], row)
                    appendCartProductWidget(products[i + 1], row)
                    appendCartProductWidget(products[i + 2], row)
                    appendCartProductWidget(products[i + 3], row)
                    div.append(row)
                }

                if (products.length % 4 !== 0) {
                    const row = getRow()
                    for (let i = 0; i < decrementCount; i++) {
                        appendCartProductWidget(products[i], row)
                    }
                    div.append(row)
                }

                $('main').append(div)
            }
        }

    }
    function getRow(): JQuery<HTMLDivElement> {
        return $('<div>', {
            'class': 'row-cols-4 row',
        })
    }
}
```

I get the following error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getAll' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction has finished.

Before I made functions asynchronous and awaited them, there were no error with transaction. I need results of ajax requests to continue to execute. How to fix this? How to make transaction doesn't finish.

Comment: I suggest not using the async qualifier on callback functions like this. Instead, create a helper function that wraps the transaction in a promise. When the transaction completes, resolve the promise. When a request errors, causing the transaction to error, reject the promise.

Comment: The IndexedDB API is designed to prevent transactions from staying alive forever, and doing arbitrary async operations within a transaction is intentionally not supported. You'll need to split the transaction in two, and/or use other coordination primitives (e.g. Web Locks).

Comment: @Josh I'm not expert in JS asynchronous programming and didn't understand what you exactly meant. I need to move my `openRequest` callback in function returning Promise in its body? What I need to pass in resolve and reject? Would it solve my issue?